# EF Code First and Performance With Large Model

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Previously, with an EF model, while there was no restriction on the number of entities in a model, it was said that for the best performance, [a model should be limited to 200 or 400 entitie](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-designer-and-large-databases/)s.  While you could have an EDMX with over 400 entities, EF may [slow down](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx) as a result.

With Code First, is there recommended size limit on a model?  Do we have a cap on the number of entities we can use in a model, before potentially running into performance problems?  I could not find information on this...

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any references to back up the claim about the number of 200-400? I'm very interested to read more about this. This might also hold for other readers. And do these numbers still hold with EF5/.NET 4.5?

Comment: @Steven Here is one example with a 50-100 number, which is lower than I heard from others elsewhere, which I heard on SO and other places.  I have not heard a definitive number from Microsoft, only in their blogs and forums: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/11/24/working-with-large-models-in-entity-framework-part-1.aspx

Comment: Another resource for EDMX: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-designer-and-large-databases/

Comment: I don't think there is a definite answer to the number since it depends on the graph and how interconnected your tables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main cause with the performance on application startup is view generation. Given that CodeFirst/DbContext API/EntityFramework.dll is just layer build on top of System.Data.Entity.dll and that the views are generated by the System.Data.Entity.dll I would assume you may expect similar behavior as far as view generation is considered.